# Manipulating Data Array in React and Graphql

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object, graphql

I'm attempting to manipulate this data in react with graphql. As you can see, I have this data or input in the graphql playground, and this is how I wanted the input to look:

[image]

In my frontend, I have a cartItem with an objects inside and array, including the product name, id, and so on. I wanted the input to look like the example I provided above. Is there a way to make that happen?

## Codes and Data

---

*This is how my **`cart's Item Data`** looks.*

### CartItem Data:

```
[
  {
    id: "6109401fd86d352a70e3694e",
    name: "asasasasa",
    sku: "sasa",
    shippingTime: "1628812800000",
    quantity: 1,
  },
  {
    id: "61051c14f25d8830a8e238c0",
    name: "Pringles Sour Cream & Onion Potato Crisps 158g",
    sku: "sad89f79dsafs",
    shippingTime: "1627084800000",
    quantity: 1,
  },
];
```

**As stated in the preceding example, all I wanted was the product's id and quantity.**

### Order.js

```
const [cartItems, setCartItems] = useContext(CartContext);

const [createOrder, { data, loading }] = useMutation(CREATE_ORDER_MUTATION);

const qty = cartItems.map(({ quantity }) => {
  return quantity;
});

const cartItemId = cartItems.map(({ id }) => {
  return id;
});


function onSubmit() {
  createOrder({
    variables: {
      qty: qty,
      products: cartItemId,
      paymentMethod: paymentMethod,
      address: address,
    },
  })
}
```

Whenever I need to console someone. If you log the `cartItemId`, you'll get something like this:
[image]

Same goes with my `qty`.

Please let me know if you have any other questions or require any additional code, and I will gladly offer it.

### Apollo Mutation:

```
const CREATE_ORDER_MUTATION = gql`
  mutation createOrder(
    $qty: Int!
    $products: String!
    $paymentMethod: String!
    $address: String!
  ) {
    createOrder(
      orderedItems: [{ qty: $qty, products: $products }]
      paymentMethod: $paymentMethod
      address: $address
    ) {
      id
      orderedItems {
        qty
        products {
          id
          name
          sku
          description
        }
      }
    }
  }
`;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code below will transform the `cartItems` into the desired result. You can loop through the cartItems and create an object with the required structure for each item.

```js
const orderedItems = cartItems.map(({ id, quantity }) => {
  return {
    qty: quantity,
    products: id,
  };
});
```

Complete code will look something like this

```
const [cartItems, setCartItems] = useContext(CartContext);
const [createOrder, { data, loading }] = useMutation(CREATE_ORDER_MUTATION);

// Restructure the array to desired format
const orderedItems = cartItems.map(({ id, quantity }) => {
  return {
    qty: quantity,
    products: id,
  };
});

console.log(orderedItems); // To check if it looks correct

function onSubmit() {
  createOrder({
    variables: {
      orderedItems: orderedItem,
      paymentMethod: paymentMethod,
      address: address,
    },
  })
}
```

Comment: Hello thanks for answering, ok will try it

Comment: seems what I want but can u please explain what do you mean by loop you mean to map it again? or something.

Comment: Could you please make it fully with the loop and stuff? if possible

Comment: I've edited the answer to include a more complete example. `map` function is already a loop. You have some data in an array, called `cartItems`, but it's not in the correct format for the API call. So, you loop over it by using the map function to return a new structure for each item.

Comment: Hello yes I tried that already it says qty and product is not provided the data

Comment: I've already edited my question I have added the what CREATE_ORDER_MUTATION looks like this is the image it return when I did the code. https://imgur.com/gEzDioh

Comment: I think you should also change the `CREATE_ORDER_MUTATION ` to be able to receive more than 1 quantity and product id.

Comment: I see, but when I tried in the playground it receives more than 1 quantity and product Id, I'll try to test to change the `CREATE_ORDER_MUTATION` so it can handle more than 1